# How would I make my app send periodic text messages at a given time?

Tags: java, android

I am using android studio with java.

I have managed to use the AlarmManager to periodically get notification at a given time. But is this possible to do with the SmsManager and does anyone have any tips on how to do it?

How I did it with AlarmManager

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,4);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,2);


AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),60*1000,null);
```

Current SmsManager

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

sms.sendTextMessage(123, null, "Text", null, null);
```

Comment: Was going about it the wrong way. I instead of doing it this way I should have started a PendingIntet that starts a Service class and run the SmsManager in the service classs onStartCommand method.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if android studio has an expecific way for doing that, but if you are using java, you can use an ScheduledExecutorService with one thread that run your task periodically.
An example should be something like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor =
Executor.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable task = ...;
executor.scheduleWithFixedRate(task, 10, 10, SECONDS);
```

Here you have more documentation about it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html